# functional component re-rendering every time I input something

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-table

i am using react-table version 7. I am using global filter for filtering, i copied some code from the sandbox and integrated it into mine, this is the link from where i copied the code [Open Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/filtering?file=/src/App.js). The problem is when ever i write something into the search bar, the whole global filter component is re-rendered and the input field loses focus and every-time, I have to click in the input field again to input text, which is very annoying as it takes time to re-render and i have to click input field everytime. why is this happening and why the same thing does not occur in the sandbox example of the react-table global filters. You can see the example on the above link i have included.

```
 return (
    <>
        <GlobalFilter
            preGlobalFilteredRows={preGlobalFilteredRows}
            globalFilter={state.globalFilter}
            setGlobalFilter={setGlobalFilter}
          />

        {/* //rest of the code*/}
         .....
    </> );

    function GlobalFilter({
      preGlobalFilteredRows,
      globalFilter,
      setGlobalFilter,
      }) {
    const count = preGlobalFilteredRows.length

    return (
      <span>
        Search:{' '}
        <input
          value={globalFilter || ''}
          onChange={e => {
            setGlobalFilter(e.target.value || undefined) // Set undefined to remove the filter entirely
          }}
          placeholder={`${count} records...`}
          style={{
            fontSize: '1.1rem',
            border: '0',
          }}
        />
      </span>
    )
  }
```

this problem does not occur if i write the code for the global filter directly inside the return statement, using this the whole component does not re-render. like this.

```
return(
  <>
  div className="row" style={{ 'zoom': '94%' }}>
            <div className="col">
                <div class="student-search-field">
                    <h4>Search: &nbsp;<input
                        value={state.globalFilter || ""}
                        onChange={e => {
                            setGlobalFilter(e.target.value || undefined); // Set undefined to remove the filter entirely
                        }}
                        placeholder={`  ${count} Students..`}
                        style={{
                            fontSize: "1.1rem",
                            border: "1",

                        }}
                    /></h4>

                </div>


            </div>

        </div>
{/* //rest of the code*/}
</>);
```

The rest of my code is like this

Hers is my complete code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useTable, usePagination, useGlobalFilter } from 'react-table';

import './classdetails.css';


function SimpleTable(props) {

const location = useLocation();
var paginationDisplay = { display: '' };
console.log(location.state);
const data = React.useMemo(
    () => [
        {
            col1: 'john doe',
            col2: "world",

        },
        {
            col1: 'react-table',
            col2: 'rocks',
        },
        {
            col1: 'whatever',
            col2: 'you want',
        },
        {
            col1: 'whatever',
            col2: 'you want',
        },
        {
            col1: 'whatever',
            col2: 'you want',

        },
        {
            col1: 'whatever',
            col2: 'you want',

        },
        {
            col1: 'whatever',
            col2: 'you want',

        },
        {
            col1: 'whatever',
            col2: 'you want',

        },
        {
            col1: 'whatever',
            col2: 'you want',

        },

    ],
    [],
);
const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
        {
            Header: 'STUDENT NAME',
            accessor: 'col1', // accessor is the "key" in the data
            Cell: (row) => {
                return (
                    <>
                        {row.row.original.col1}
                        <p>FA16-BCS-067</p>
                    </>);
            },

        },
        {
            Header: 'ATTENDANCE',
            accessor: 'col2',// use accessor name in hidden column to hide a column e.g intitalstate.hiddenColumns['col2']
        },
        {
            Header: 'QUIZEZ',
            accessor: '',

        },
        {
            Header: 'ASSIGNMENT',
            accessor: '',
        },
        {
            Header: 'FIRST TERM',
            accessor: '',
        },
        {
            Header: 'MID TERM',
            accessor: '',

        },
        {
            Header: 'FINAL TERM',
            accessor: '',

        },
        {
            Header: 'action',
            accessor: '',
            Cell: (row) => {
                return (
                    <button className="btn btn-danger"
                        onClick={() => console.log(row.row)}
                    >
                        View
                    </button>);
            },

        },
    ],
    [],
);


  function GlobalFilter({
    preGlobalFilteredRows,
    globalFilter,
    setGlobalFilter,
  }) {
    const count = preGlobalFilteredRows.length

    return (
      <span>
        Search:{' '}
        <input
          value={globalFilter || ''}
          onChange={e => {
            setGlobalFilter(e.target.value || undefined) // Set undefined to remove the filter entirely
          }}
          placeholder={`${count} records...`}
          style={{
            fontSize: '1.1rem',
            border: '0',
          }}
        />
      </span>
    )
  }



const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    page,
    prepareRow,
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    setPageSize,
    pageOptions,
    state,
    preGlobalFilteredRows,
    setGlobalFilter,
    state: { pageIndex, pageSize }

} = useTable({ columns, data, initialState: { pageIndex: 0, pageSize: 5, hiddenColumns: [''] } },
    useGlobalFilter, usePagination);



const count = preGlobalFilteredRows.length;
return (
    <>

        <GlobalFilter
            preGlobalFilteredRows={preGlobalFilteredRows}
            globalFilter={state.globalFilter}
            setGlobalFilter={setGlobalFilter}
          />


        {/* //table section */}

        <div className="row">
            <div className="col table-div-1 highlight table-2" style={{ 'overflowY': 'auto', 'height': '455px' }}>
                <table {...getTableProps()}>
                    <thead>
                        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
                            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                                {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                                    <th
                                        {...column.getHeaderProps()}
                                    >
                                        {column.render('Header')}
                                    </th>
                                ))}
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </thead>
                    <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                        {page.map(row => {
                            prepareRow(row)
                            return (
                                <tr key={123} {...row.getRowProps()} >
                                    {row.cells.map(cell => {
                                        return (
                                            <td
                                                {...cell.getCellProps()}
                                                onClick={() => console.log()}
                                            >
                                                {cell.render('Cell')}
                                            </td>
                                        )
                                    })}
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        {/* //pagination section */}

    { props === props ? <>
        <div className="row pagination" style={paginationDisplay}>
            <span>
                Page{' '}
                <strong>
                    {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
                </strong>{' '}
            </span>
            <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => previousPage()} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
                {'<'}
            </button>{" "}
            <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => nextPage()} disabled={!canNextPage}>
                {'>'}
            </button>{" "}
            <select className="btn btn-danger"
                value={pageSize}
                onChange={e => {
                    setPageSize(Number(e.target.value));
                    console.log(pageSize);
                }}
            >
                {[5, 10, 20, 30].map(pageSize => (
                    <option key={pageSize.value} value={pageSize}>
                        Show {pageSize}
                    </option>
                ))}
            </select>
        </div>
        </> : null }
    </>

);
   }

  export default SimpleTable;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made the correction of your **complete code**. You did not use Table function from the Sandbox(from where you copied the code). I tested the following which is **working fine** and fulfil your requirement. please have a look.

```
import React from 'react';
import {useTable, usePagination, useGlobalFilter} from 'react-table';
import matchSorter from 'match-sorter'

function SimpleTable(props) {

    var paginationDisplay = {display: ''};

    const data = React.useMemo(
        () => [
            {
                col1: 'john doe',
                col2: "world",
            },
            {
                col1: 'react-table',
                col2: 'rocks',
            },
            {
                col1: 'whatever',
                col2: 'you want',
            },
            {
                col1: 'whatever',
                col2: 'you want',
            },
            {
                col1: 'whatever',
                col2: 'you want',
            },
            {
                col1: 'whatever',
                col2: 'you want',
            },
            {
                col1: 'whatever',
                col2: 'you want',
            },
            {
                col1: 'whatever',
                col2: 'you want',
            },
            {
                col1: 'whatever',
                col2: 'you want',
            },
        ],
        [],
    );

    const columns = React.useMemo(
        () => [
            {
                Header: 'STUDENT NAME',
                accessor: 'col1', // accessor is the "key" in the data
                Cell: (row) => {
                    return (
                        <>
                            {row.row.original.col1}
                            <p>FA16-BCS-067</p>
                        </>);
                },

            },
            {
                Header: 'ATTENDANCE',
                accessor: 'col2',// use accessor name in hidden column to hide a column e.g intitalstate.hiddenColumns['col2']
            },
            {
                Header: 'QUIZEZ',
                accessor: '',

            },
            {
                Header: 'ASSIGNMENT',
                accessor: '',
            },
            {
                Header: 'FIRST TERM',
                accessor: '',
            },
            {
                Header: 'MID TERM',
                accessor: '',
            },
            {
                Header: 'FINAL TERM',
                accessor: '',
            },
            {
                Header: 'action',
                accessor: '',
                Cell: (row) => {
                    return (
                        <button className="btn btn-danger"
                                onClick={() => console.log(row.row)}
                        >
                            View
                        </button>);
                },
            },
        ],
        [],
    );

    function GlobalFilter({
                              preGlobalFilteredRows,
                              globalFilter,
                              setGlobalFilter,
                          }) {
        const count = preGlobalFilteredRows.length

        return (
            <span>
        Search:{' '}
                <input
                    value={globalFilter || ''}
                    onChange={e => {
                        setGlobalFilter(e.target.value || undefined) // Set undefined to remove the filter entirely
                    }}
                    placeholder={`${count} records...`}
                    style={{
                        fontSize: '1.1rem',
                        border: '0',
                    }}
                />
      </span>
        )
    }


    function fuzzyTextFilterFn(rows, id, filterValue) {
        return matchSorter(rows, filterValue, {keys: [row => row.values[id]]})
    }

    // Our table component
    function Table({columns, data}) {
        const filterTypes = React.useMemo(
            () => ({
                // Add a new fuzzyTextFilterFn filter type.
                fuzzyText: fuzzyTextFilterFn,
                // Or, override the default text filter to use
                // "startWith"
                text: (rows, id, filterValue) => {
                    return rows.filter(row => {
                        const rowValue = row.values[id]
                        return rowValue !== undefined
                            ? String(rowValue)
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .startsWith(String(filterValue).toLowerCase())
                            : true
                    })
                },
            }),
            []
        );

        const {
            getTableProps,
            getTableBodyProps,
            headerGroups,
            page,
            prepareRow,
            canPreviousPage,
            canNextPage,
            nextPage,
            previousPage,
            setPageSize,
            pageOptions,
            state,
            preGlobalFilteredRows,
            setGlobalFilter,
            state: {pageIndex, pageSize}

        } = useTable({columns, data, initialState: {pageIndex: 0, pageSize: 5, hiddenColumns: ['']}},
            useGlobalFilter, usePagination);

        const count = preGlobalFilteredRows.length;
        return (
            <>
                <GlobalFilter
                    preGlobalFilteredRows={preGlobalFilteredRows}
                    globalFilter={state.globalFilter}
                    setGlobalFilter={setGlobalFilter}
                />

                {/* //table section */}

                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col table-div-1 highlight table-2" style={{'overflowY': 'auto', 'height': '455px'}}>
                        <table {...getTableProps()}>
                            <thead>
                            {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
                                <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                                    {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                                        <th
                                            {...column.getHeaderProps()}
                                        >
                                            {column.render('Header')}
                                        </th>
                                    ))}
                                </tr>
                            ))}
                            </thead>
                            <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                            {page.map(row => {
                                prepareRow(row);
                                return (
                                    <tr key={123} {...row.getRowProps()} >
                                        {row.cells.map(cell => {
                                            return (
                                                <td
                                                    {...cell.getCellProps()}
                                                    onClick={() => console.log()}
                                                >
                                                    {cell.render('Cell')}
                                                </td>
                                            )
                                        })}
                                    </tr>
                                )
                            })}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {/* //pagination section */}

                {props === props ? <>
                    <div className="row pagination" style={paginationDisplay}>
            <span>
                Page{' '}
                <strong>
                    {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
                </strong>{' '}
            </span>
                        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => previousPage()} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
                            {'<'}
                        </button>
                        {" "}
                        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => nextPage()} disabled={!canNextPage}>
                            {'>'}
                        </button>
                        {" "}
                        <select className="btn btn-danger"
                                value={pageSize}
                                onChange={e => {
                                    setPageSize(Number(e.target.value));
                                    console.log(pageSize);
                                }}
                        >
                            {[5, 10, 20, 30].map(pageSize => (
                                <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
                                    Show {pageSize}
                                </option>
                            ))}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </> : null}
            </>
        );
    }

    return (
        <Table columns={columns} data={data}/>
    )
}

export default SimpleTable;
```

Comment: it does not have any effect. The globalFilter re-renders.

Comment: @newbie, can you provide complete example so that we run and reproduce your issue?

Comment: the third code block has the complete code, you just need to render it, exclude the css file, it will work.

Comment: @newbie, I have made the correction and updated my answer. it is working. Please check it.

Comment: its working now thanks a lot. But can you be so kind and explain why the global filter is not re-rendering everytime i write something in it. I am a bit confused as why it was re-rendering before and not now.

Comment: Hi @newbie, you are welcome, I think global filter is not rendering every time because of useGlobalFilter that came from react-table. I believe useGlobalFilter hook handles rendering issue.

Comment: It worked on me too. I spent hours on this problem, thanks! The problem is because of this code. You should return separately.

return (
        <Table columns={columns} data={data}/>
    )